# Inserts to identity attribute producing unexpected results

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo, identity

I have a table

```
MovieInfo
M_ID int idenity
title varchar
yearReleased int    
Primary key ( title, yearReleased)
```

My php file to insert values into the table:

```
try{
     $host = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=localhost;Database='.$database, $username, $password);

        $movieTitle = $_POST['title'];
        $movieYear = $_POST['year'];


        $stmt = "INSERT INTO MovieInfo (title, yearReleased) VALUES (:title, :year)";
        $q = $host->prepare($stmt);
        $q->execute(array(':title'=>$movieTitle, ':year'=>$movieYear));

        $host = null;
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die('Connect not connect: '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

My table is populating fine, but the M_ID which gets auto updated is isn't updating incrementally like 1,2,3,4,5. Instead my values for that column are 1,3,4,6,7,10,11. I'm curious if this is expected or something is different. If I try to insert a duplicate it does not run which is expected. It seems though that the M_ID is getting incremented everytime, even on failed inserts.

Comment: You probably meant to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` and what is `idenity`? Or, is that just a copy/paste typo?

Comment: By design.  Auto increment id's don't roll back once they've been consumed.  When you order food, if it's bad, it doesn't get served again. (at least it shouldn't be)  in addition if deletes occur voids will begin to occur in the identify.  It's just a number voids are to be expected.

Comment: Depends on how bad the food was! @xQbert then yeah... they could take it back - grin

Comment: Ooooooook. I confused myself on what identity actually represents. I'll change it to an auto increment. Thanks guys, this site is always helpful

Comment: That's what I thought @MickB I had a funny feeling about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is how IDENTITY works.  The value is incremented regardless of the success or failure of the INSERT statement.